# How can I add the tracking number to the message the users receive?

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

I have tried editing uc_order module

```
function uc_order_token_list($type = 'all') {
  ...
  $tokens['order']['order-tracking-number'] = t('The tracking number of the order.');
  ...
}

function uc_order_token_values($type, $object = NULL) {
  ...
  $values['order-tracking-number'] = uc_tracking_get_order_tracking_numbers($order);
}
```

Email Message:

```
[order-first-name] [order-last-name], Your order number [order-link] at [store-name] has been updated. Order status: [order-status] Order tracking number: [order-tracking-number] Order comment: [order-last-comment] Browse to the following page to login to your account and view your order details: [site-login] Thanks again, [store-name] [site-slogan]
```

But in the message the user receives, the tracking number is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this did work, I just did not have an actual tracking number for my order since it was a test order, it never actually got shipped.